# Blazor Server - the circuit failed to initialize

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I have published the BlazorApp1 app created by the VS2019 Blazor template to a production server. Since it is a sub-site, I made 3 changes:

1. in `_Host.cshtml` replaced the base tag with `<base href="/BlazorApp1/" >`
2. in `Startup.cs` added `app.UsePathBase("/BlazorApp1")`
3. in `web.config`, changed the `hostingModel` to `outofprocess` and `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true`

When navigating to the site I almost always get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception Page must be reloaded

This is displayed in the browser console: (replaced my site with contoso)

```
[2020-06-02T18:39:49.445Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_blazor'. blazor.server.js:1:5212
[2020-06-02T18:39:49.936Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_blazor?id=5yq6pI_jo1ByPZtskEjjmw. blazor.server.js:1:5212
[2020-06-02T18:39:50.132Z] Error: The circuit failed to initialize. blazor.server.js:15:27309
    log http://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:15
    C http://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:8
    S http://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:8
    invokeClientMethod http://www.contoso.com/BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    invokeClientMethod .../BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    processIncomingData .../BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    onreceive .../BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    onmessage .../BlazorApp1/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
[2020-06-02T18:39:50.141Z] Information: Connection disconnected. blazor.server.js:1:5212
Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed. blazor.server.js:1:20001
```

I can't find any other clues about what's happening. There are no exceptions shown in the log.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was resolved by using only lowercase characters in the `<base>` tag:

```html
  <base href="/blazorapp1/" >
```

Comment: This is exactly right, in my case my webapp was on a subdomain and ofc its all in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened because I put an async call inside a constructor of a class in DI, so, yeah, that's a stupid error which can mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

It has just happened to me as well, but I had the `base` tag specified correctly. This error can also occur in a rare case when you have ambiguous constructors defined for one of your dependency injected services if both match all the parameters (possibly by accident due to inheritance). The verbose log won't point to that issue. Be aware that purposeful creation of multiple constructors for dependency injected services is considered an [anti-pattern](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/).

Answer (score -1):

simply, install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client and configure signalr correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).